# Accepted way to pass programatic information to an xml instanciated class

Tags: android

this app has a custom view class, which only contains a canvas, with which the user interacts (something like a drawing widget for example). This class can be called from several different activities, and always is part of a layout containing additional widgets like Buttons and EditTexts.
These layouts are built in xml, since this is the accepted way, and the custom view itself will be initialised like this :

```
                setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
                final CustomView view = (CustomView) this.findViewById(R.id.customView);
                view.setup(param1, param2);
```

the code in setup() is indispensable - every single instance of CustomView requires param1 and param2 values - and should therefore ideally run in the constructor, but I don't think there is a way to both instantiate from xml, and pass programmatic values.
Am I correct in thinking so, and is this the normal way to initialize my custom view in such a case?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you did is right. But if you already know what `param1` and `param2` are and if they fall under the `attribute` category, then you might as well set them as attibutes in your xml where you have the `CustomView`.

If that's not the case, then what you have done is the right way and the best way at it.

Comment: Nope, they are numbers of the user's choosing. Thanks for your answer, Henry.